# How to position user typed-in content in search bar input?

Tags: html, css, placeholder, searchbar

I am working on a search bar for my site. It is positioned correctly on the site, it's styled and everything works just fine, I added a placeholder and positioned/styled it inside the search bar as I liked it to fit the rest of my site. If I click inside the search bar and write anything, the written letters appear in the default position of the placeholder (middle of the search bar), but I want them to be positioned differently (more to the left and lower), like the placeholder.
[The placeholder looks good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHhbp.jpg) but the
[typed-in text doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doQak.jpg).

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Suche..." />
```

The search bar is styled as following:

```
#searchbar {
  grid-area: search;
  font-size: max(var(--ändern), 20px);
  font-family: var(--schriftart);
  background-color: var(--hintergrundfarbe);
  color: var(--schriftfarbe);
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 0.75vw;
  border-color: var(--hintergrundfarbe);
  text-align: center;
  width: 15vw;
  height: max(2.5vw, calc(150px / 4));
  margin-left: 1.25vw;
  margin-top: 0.5vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

The placeholder is styled as following:

```
#searchbar::placeholder {
  color: var(--schriftfarbe);
  filter: opacity(0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

I tried to use

```
#searchbar:focus {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

but it shifts the whole search bar, not only the the typed-in content.
I also tried

```
text-indent: 40px;
```

but doesn't seem to change anything either. I would be happy for anyone trying to help me :)

Comment: Please add the variables, that you use.

Comment: sure, its': `:root {
  --hintergrundfarbe: rgb(182, 97, 22);
  --schriftfarbe: rgb(255, 234, 0);
  --schriftfarbe-hover: rgb(231, 181, 3);
  --schriftfarbe-active: white;
  --schriftart: Javanese Text;
  --überschriftart: Matura MT Script Capitals;
  --ändern: 1.25vw;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks it might be your font-family. Try a different font like Arial for tests.

```
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: That's true, it looks like it wasn't supported in the input field, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this:

```
#searchbar input[type=text]{
/*write your css here*/

  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Nope sorry, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```css
:root {   
--hintergrundfarbe: rgb(182, 97, 22);   
--schriftfarbe: rgb(255, 234, 0);   
--schriftfarbe-hover: rgb(231, 181, 3);   
--schriftfarbe-active: white;   
--schriftart: Javanese Text;   
--überschriftart: Matura MT Script Capitals;   
--ändern: 1.25vw; }

#searchbar {
  grid-area: search;
  font-size: max(var(--ändern), 20px);
  font-family: var(--schriftart);
  background-color: var(--hintergrundfarbe);
  color: var(--schriftfarbe);
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 0.75vw;
  border-color: var(--hintergrundfarbe);
  width: 15vw;
  height: max(2.5vw, calc(150px / 4));
  margin-left: 1.25vw;
  margin-top: 0.5vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-top:10px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#searchbar::placeholder {
  color: var(--schriftfarbe);
  filter: opacity(0.5);
}
```

```html
<input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Suche..." />
```